# AccessControlException when attempting to delete a file

Tags: java, security, servlets, filesystems, io

We have a java web service application that uses log4j to do logging. An  exception gets thrown when log4j tries to delete its rolling log files

```
Exception:java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
(java.io.FilePermission /var/opt/SUNWappserver/domains/domain1/
applications/j2ee-modules/ourwebservice/WEB-INF/logs/IMWrapper.log.10 delete)
```

When we do an `ls` in the directory the service account does have access to read and write to the files and the directory.

From some initial Googling it seems we may have to change the `security.policy` file to allow the service to delete files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quickfix you can start the application using a policy file with the following content:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

using the command line option:

-Djava.security.policy=file:<your_policy_file>

See [this link](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html) for more info how to configure your policy file to get the required access rights.

EDIT: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to configure your web application how to use that policy file, but at least the link should hint you towards getting the required rights...