# Script that uses variable username in find command

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that lists the absolute paths of all of a given user's home files and directories, recursively, and writes all of them to an array.  Currently, I'm using find like so ...

```
user="foobar"
usersHomeFiles=( $(find ~$user -printf "%p\\n") )
```

However, when I execute this script it tells me ...

```
find: `~foobar': No such file or directory
```

Even though `foobar` is a valid user with a home directory.  I even get the same error running it with `user="root"`.  Any ideas how I could fix this so the find command works in my script?

Comment: use zsh instead of bash

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14931757/1126841) to a related question may help, although it comes with the same caveat as my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because in bash "tilde expansion" happens before "parameter expansion". So tilde expansion attempts to find user "$user", this fails and the tilde remains unchanged. Next comes "parameter expansion" substituting "$user" with "foobar". See bash(1) "EXPANSION" section.

One way to do this is with "eval", like this:

```
user_home=`eval "echo ~$user"`
```

Another is directly querying the passwd database, like this:

```
user_home=`getent passwd "$user" | cut -d: -f6`
```

However, note that your array assignment will break if user home directory contains filenames with spaces or tabs.

You can read them more reliably with "readarray", like this:

```
readarray -t usersHomeFiles < <(find "$user_home")
```

Answer (score 2):

Tilde expansion occurs prior to parameter expansion, so the tilde `~$user` is left as-is. You'll need something like

```
userHome=$( eval "echo ~$user" )
userHomeFiles=( $( find "$userHome" -print '%p\n' ) )
```

although I hope someone will post an `eval`-free solution. This is not safe unless you are absolutely sure of the contents of `user`.

Comment: to avoid eval, couldn't you do something like userhome=$( echo "~${user}" )... nope, just tried it and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a couple of options to your find command, i.e. the path where find starts to search from and the -name flag i.e.:

```
$(find /home/$user -name "*" -printf "%p\\n")
```